# surf - matching objects using matched points

Tags: sift, surf

I am trying to find the best matching objects in two images. I am using SURF descriptors and I find matching points in two images. My question is, how to match two objects (not points) using matched points. for example, in the image, the most matched points belong to "1"s; should I say that because "1"s have the most number of matching points, they are the best matching objects? or should I do that based on the euclidean distances between point descriptors? If so, what if the best matching point belongs to "2-4" pair, but the second and third best matching points belong to "1"s, etc.? 
I would appreciate any help.

[image]

Comment: It is not clear, what you want to archive. However, using SURF for the the matching binary image of digits is definitely not a good idea.

Comment: Thanks old-ufo. Why isn't this a good idea? What is a good matching algorithm for matching binary images of digits?

Comment: Because SURF is designed and good for textured grayscale images. Read how it works. About digits - for example try Google Tesseract. And google OCR libraries or software, there are quite lot of them.